# Loop to concatenate multiple pairs of files with almost the same name in UNIX

Tags: loops, cat, fastq

I have a very basic question, but I can't get a solution. I have multiple files in the same directory and I would like to concatenate each pair of files. The names are:

Sample1_R1_L001.fastq
Sample1_R2_L001.fastq
Sample2_R1_L001.fastq
Sample2_R2_L001.fastq
Sample3_R1_L001.fastq
Sample3_R2_L001.fastq

(etc...)

The result I want is to concatenate by sample, such as
cat Sample1_R1_L001.fastq Sample1_R2_L001.fastq > Sample1_concat.fastq

I tried this loop, 
find . -name "*_R?_*"|while read file; do "$file"*R1**.fastq "$file"_R2_L001.fastq > "$file"_merged.fastq

but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: To be more precise, the filenames are a bit more complicated (something like MTNT-Enr-BS_S70_L001_R1_001.fastq), and I have one pair for each sample (thus MTNT-Enr-BS_S70_L001_R1_001.fastq and MTNT-Enr-BS_S70_L001_R2_001.fastq). I might try simplifying the names, but in the long run, I would like to be able to just run the loop without much adjustment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
for i in {1..4}; do echo cat Sample"$i"* > combined_"$i".txt; done
```

Loop over the numbers then build the command... getting the actual filenames is surely possible, but with shell, I just do the simplest thing that can possibly work, even if that means partially brute forcing the loop.

Replace the 1..4 to whatever the limits are and the shell will expand that into all the various numbers for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Actually, the file names are a bit more complicated (more like MTNT-Enr-BS_S70_L001_R1_001.fastq), and I have one pair for each sample (thus MTNT-Enr-BS_S70_L001_R1_001.fastq and MTNT-Enr-BS_S70_L001_R2_001.fastq). I might try simplifying the names, but in the long run, I would like to be able to just run the loop without much adjustment. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure without seeing a bigger example of names. Like I said, with shell, I tend to just do a quick hacky solution based on the specific problem

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..3}; 
do for j in 1 2; 
do cat 6692_S${i}_S${i}_*_R${j}_001.fastq.gz >  6692_S${i}_R${j}_concatenate.fastq.gz; 
done; 
done
```

#My sample name as example 6692_S1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz; 6692_S1_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz

I think you can tailor to your needs.

Comment: Thank you Benoit!