# Concatenating Pairs of Files with Specific Naming Scheme (UBUNTU)

Tags: bash, concatenation, ubuntu-14.04

**There appears to be a partial answer here, but the user encountered the same problem I did: it's important to preserve the original naming scheme.

[Loop to concatenate multiple pairs of files with almost the same name in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019344/loop-to-concatenate-multiple-pairs-of-files-with-almost-the-same-name-in-unix)**

I have a folder with paired files; the names look like this (all stored in the same folder/directory):

MX_HF20.1.fq.gz;
MX_HF20.rem.1.fq.gz

MX_HF22.1.fq.gz;
MX_HF22.rem.1.fq.gz

.

.

.

SD_F296.1.fq.gz;
SD_F296.rem.1.fq.gz

SD_F297.1.fq.gz;
SD_F297.rem.1.fq.gz

(Some of you might recognize this as STACKS output!)

Really, I'm just looking to append the contents of the *.1.rem.fq.gz file to the end of the *.1.fq.gz file, keeping the original *.1.fq.gz file's name.

I've toyed around with test files, so I know cat will do this even though the files are .gz. But my bash scripting abilities are poor at best, and working with and storing name variables is a concept I'm still struggling to grasp.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using bash rematch:

```
#!/bin/bash

p='([A-Z]+_[A-Z]+)([0-9]+)\.1\.rem\.fq\.gz'

for f in *.gz; do
    if [[ $f =~ $p ]]; then
        cat "${f}" >> "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.1.fq.gz"
    fi
done
```

So for example:

`SD_F297.1.rem.fq.gz` would be appended to `SD_F297.1.fq.gz`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried this, and the script runs with no errors, but it doesn't seem to change either file at all  (I've made much smaller, simpler text files (gzipped) with identical names to the ones above). 

I did try changing the *.txt term to *.fq.gz, and the result was the same. Could there be something I'm missing there? Perhaps the script isn't finding anything to operate on.

Comment: @canfiese: It should work, and I'm surprised it didn't. Maybe try putting "echo" in front of "cat" to see what happens. The echo won't change the file but should show you what might be happening.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm an idiot. The naming scheme above is incorrect. It should be *.rem.1.fq.gz. I switched it around and it did do something...but it made my test file 175 MB (from 16 bytes), and it wouldn't open. Which is odd, but I've seen it before. Must be a peculiarity of .gz...

Comment: I got it to work. I accidentally switched something around, and I think it caused the strange behavior. Thank you!

Switching the .rem with the .1 was the charm. Sorry for the headache.

Comment: You're welcome! And no worries, it happens, and glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file1 in *.1.fq.gz;  do
   file2=`echo $file1 | sed -E 's/(*\.1)\.fq\.gz/\1.rem.fq.gz/'`
   cat $file1 $file2 > out.$file1
done
```

Backquotes execute a shell command and insert the text result to that point in your script

sed is the stream editor in unix that manipulates lines of text

It uses regular expressions, and in this case you need () to group and capture the first part of the file name and \1 to reference it

Comment: (Edited) @zakum1 Thanks! This looks like it's really on the right track (from what little experience I have). But I do get the following error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 30: Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: Also, it may make a difference...but I did have to edit my file-name system. It's *.rem.1.fq.gz  Egg all over my face. Sorry. :/